# Is my solution of this probability correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The problem goes as follow:

"A group of $n $ friends decided to play secret santa (kris kringel in UK). What is the probability that at least one person been assigned with itself in the game?"

My approach to this problem was to think of each assigment of names as a permutation of the friends. Thus, in order to solve the problem one must only find out the number of permutation of $n $ objects that fixes at least one of them. 
It turns out to be equal to number of total permutations (i.e. $n! $) minus the number of permutation that does not fixes any object. 
If we think of permutation as cycles, the permutations that does not fixes any object is precisely the cycles of lenght $ n $. Every cycle of length $n $ has $n $ distincts representations

Example:

$ (123) = (231) = (312) $

Thus, we have $ n!/n = (n-1)! $ cycles of length $ n $.

Therefore the probability is equal to

$ (n! - (n-1)!)/n! = (n-1)/n $

Is my reasoning correct?

Is there a easier way to come to the solution?

Any tips or recomendation will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

(Sorry for the english)

Comment: "*A group of friends decided to play secret santa.  What is the probability that at least one person been assigned with itself in the game*"  The probability is zero if they went about it in an intelligent way.  How are they deciding who gets assigned who?  Are we looking at a uniformly randomly selected permutation and asking if it has any fixed points?  If so, have you ever heard of derangements?

Comment: You need to look into *derangements*.  Also, there are ways to get derangements other than by cycles of length $n$.  For example, with $4$ people, $1$ and $2$ can get swapped, as well as $3$ and $4$

Comment: Random assigment. No, i have never heard before, i'll search for, thanks.

Comment: The answer of the probability that a uniformly randomly selected permutation has at least one fixed point is not going to be $\frac{n-1}{n}$, it will be $\frac{n!-!n}{n!}$ which tends towards $1-\frac{1}{e}\approx 0.632$.  If you wish to come up with an expression for $!n$ on your own without relying on other people's work, consider using inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake when you say that "the permutations that do not fix any object are precisely the cycles of lenght $n$".
For instance, the permutation $(12)(34)$ does not fix any object, but is not a single cycle.

Do you think you can take it from here?